# looping database results using MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to pull a list of registration information from MySQL. I'm changing the query over to object oriented and when I did this, the results are not being displayed inside the table. No error messages are being displayed.

```
<?php   

                    $sql     = "SELECT * FROM `prereg`";
                    if (!$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM prereg")) {
                        echo "Query Failed!: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") ". $mysqli->error;
                    }else{

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc()) {                                   
            ?>
                <tr>
               <!-- <td>
                        <?php echo $row['UID']; ?>
                    </td> -->
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['Guradian']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['Number']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['Phone']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['Name']; ?>
                    </td>
               <!-- <td>
                        <?php echo $row['Address']; ?>
                    </td> -->
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['City']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['State']; ?>
                    </td>
               <!-- <td>
                        <?php echo $row['Zip']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php print $row['Make']; ?>
                    </td> 
                    <td>
                        <?php print $row['Ms']; ?>
                    </td> -->
                    <td>
                        <?php print $row['Fuel']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['Class1']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php print $row['Class2']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php print $row['Class3']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                        <?php } }
                    $stmt->free(); ?>
```

What am I doing wrong? I've searched and searched and I cannot find anything that fixes the problem.

REVISED:

```
<?php   
                    $stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM prereg");
                    if($stmt->num_rows > 0):
                        while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()):                                    
            ?>
                <tr>
               <!-- <td>
                        <?php echo $row['UID']; ?>
                    </td> -->
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['Guradian']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['Number']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['Phone']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['Name']; ?>
                    </td>
               <!-- <td>
                        <?php echo $row['Address']; ?>
                    </td> -->
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['City']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['State']; ?>
                    </td>
               <!-- <td>
                        <?php echo $row['Zip']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php print $row['Make']; ?>
                    </td> 
                    <td>
                        <?php print $row['Ms']; ?>
                    </td> -->
                    <td>
                        <?php print $row['Fuel']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['Class1']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php print $row['Class2']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php print $row['Class3']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
            </table>

            <?php
            $stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM prereg"); 

             if($stmt->num_rows > 0): ?>
                <table>
            <?php while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()): ?>
                    <tr>
                    <?php foreach($row as $val): ?>
                        <td><?php echo $val; ?></td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </table>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </center>
```

when trying to retrofit the code you have provided with the table I already had, the code you gave works, the table I have still wont populate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the procedural interface [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), you need to provide the `mysqli_result`.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
```

If you'd use the object oriented interface, then just use it as its method:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Revised:

```
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');
$stmt = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM prereg');
?>

<?php if($stmt->num_rows > 0): ?>
<table>
    <?php while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()): ?>
        <tr>
        <?php foreach($row as $val): ?>
            <td><?php echo $val; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
<?php else :?>
<p>Table empty</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Ok, I made that change. Before hand the table is should be displaying showed only the table header. After the change it shows the header and a blank row. Still no data results.

Comment: @EdHamilton just make sure the table is indeed not empty.

Comment: That returned everything. Now I just need to figure out how to return that result within the table i built. The results returned on that query are all over the place. There is nothing seperating one field from the other, and it isn't useable for what i need in the current form.

Comment: @EdHamilton well i won't be seeing anything fetching on my end :D, i can only help on how to use the fetch function. anyway you could just use the individual echoing of each index, ie: `echo $row['Guardian']`, and others. that inner foreach loop was just a shortcut/cleaner of echoing all values. customize the looks by css to your liking.

Comment: It seems that without that foreach the results will not populate the table.

Comment: @EdHamilton quite easy to debug, inside the `while()` block, use `print_r($row);`. or `var_dump($row);` so that you know what to expect